# How to pass context from Script to another Class groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui

Below is my Groovy Script which instantiates my classes. It is a part of a much larger Groovy Script, consisting of many classes, which sits as a Test Case within a Test Suite in SoapUI :

```
public class Run extends Script {
public static void main (String[] args){
    Run mainRun = new Run()
}
public run(){
    def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context ); // Would not error
    Model myModel = new Model()
    View myView = new View()
    Controller myController = new Controller()
    myModel.addObserver (myView)
    myController.addModel(myModel)
    myController.addView(myView)
    myController.initModel("Init Message")
    myView.addController(myController)
}}
```

Within the above 'Run' class, (if I wanted to), I am able to refer to the 'context' - in order to define GroovyUtils. How do I pass the 'context' to another class, the Model, in order to use GroovyUtils in the Model? I.e:

```
class Model extends java.util.Observable {
public String doSomething(){
    def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context );// Error occurs here
    return "Stuff that needs groovyUtils"
}}
```

The above code would cause an error when trying to refer to the context, despite it being within the same Groovy Test Step as the 'Run' class. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not just pass groovyUtils to the method?  Why do you have to get it in two places?

Comment: I dont know how to pass it to the method. Because the 'Run' class never communicates directly with the methods in the 'Model' class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly all the pieces of your model, however as @tim_yates suggest in his comment why you don't simply pass the `groovyUtils` to your `Model` class. You can modify your `Model` class adding a `groovyUtils` variable:

```
class Model extends java.util.Observable {

    com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils groovyUtils

    public String doSomething(){
            println this.groovyUtils// here you've groovy utils
            return "Stuff that needs groovyUtils"
    }   
}
```

And then in the `run()` method pass the `groovyUtils` to the `Model` class using the groovy default map constructor:

```
public class Run extends Script {
public static void main (String[] args){
    Run mainRun = new Run()
}
public run(){
    def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context ); // Would not error
    Model myModel = new Model('groovyUtils':groovyUtils) // pass the groovyUtils to your Model
    assert "Stuff that needs groovyUtils" == myModel.doSomething() // only to check the groovyUtils is passed to your model class
    assert myModel.groovyUtils == groovyUtils
    ...
}}
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thankyou very much - that was exactly what I needed!