# Passing the webdriver instance between groovy scripts?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, groovy, soapui

We've been trying to figure out how to call, (0)from a groovy script, (1)a selenium website login and then a (2) call the navigation (script) portion sitting in another test case. Running both independently works 100%. Below is the code that I use to call both the scripts from (0) but, once it's done with `login.run`, a new browser is opened with `select.run` and obviously the test fails because it's not logged in.

```
login = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.testSuites["Selenium"].testCases["Login"].testSteps["Login_Plat"]
select = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.testSuites["Selenium"].testCases["Calculator"].testSteps["GS_Platinum"]

login.run(testRunner, context)
select.run(testRunner, context)
```

So I went and manipulated the `login`, `select`(by removing webdriver code)and main script code now looks like this(i've excluded the imports in this paste):

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue("driverPath"))
env = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue("testEnvDetails1")
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver()

driver.get(env)

login = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.testSuites["Selenium"].testCases["Login"].testSteps["Login_Plat"]
select = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.testSuites["Selenium"].testCases["Calculator"].testSteps["GS_Platinum"]
login.run(testRunner, context)
select.run(testRunner, context)
```

I find this in the error log of the failed login script (when I run script  0) `ERROR:groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: driver for class: Script19` so it looks like the (1)`login` script isn't using the `driver` class from the main script(0)

I've looked at these similar issues too, but ours seemed to be too different from theirs.

[selenium webdriver inside soapui, passing the driver instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22248196/selenium-webdriver-inside-soapui-passing-the-driver-instance)

[How to pass context from Script to another Class groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33437415/how-to-pass-context-from-script-to-another-class-groovy)

[How to define a global class in SoapUI as a groovy script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11742995/define-a-global-class-in-soapuis-groovy-script?rq=1)

and I'm trying very hard to avoid `.jar` into `ext` dir way, simply because we want to avoid at all costs(training mostly) using another program to do this. It is also a lot more efficient if we can see the code being called instead of importing it into a script as the website is being changed.

All three of these scripts are in the same project and test suite, but different test cases. This was done because there are going to be multiple test steps/scripts inside the login test case with different login ways and details. I'm using webdriver standalone server

Comment: Looks the description is little confusing when you say, "**I'm not passing the same driver from the original script that gets run - I've tried doing all the imports and driver  stuff inside the main runner script and just have the general selenium code called to no avail.**" Can you please edit the question and clarify the details like what you mean by main script? How is your test case / test suite defined? What is driver for you running it from `soapUI`, rather than using it from _outside_ like `command-line`? And why are you trying to avoid `.jar`?

Comment: @Rao hope its clearer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Let me first clear few points.*

- by default, the **variable defined in one `groovy script` can't be accessed in second groovy script** *irrespective of where groovy scripts are located*
- one can't use the properties[test case / suite / project] for storing complex objects, due to the fact that `soapui` uses `StringToString Map`

**What is the way:**
Groovy Script, by default, has access to below variables:

```
- context
- testRunner
- log
```

So, `context` something that you can leverage to initialize the object in one place and access it anywhere. This depends on in which context the object is initialized or set, nevertheless to say, use the same context while retrieving the object. This way, `Webdriver` instance is created once and accessed using other `context` variables.

> **Note:** The initialization has to be done before accessing the object for the first time. Otherwise, it will end up with `NullpointerException`

Here I wanted to suggest to set the required object at `Project level`, so that the same object is available anywhere with in the *soapUI project*. However, it does not stop you to use test suite / case levels as well.

Below are the *additional statement(s) required* in your `first groovy script`. Please keep it after the `driver` object is created.

**Set / Initializing driver object:**

```
    //your existing code goes here  
    def projectContext = context.testCase.testSuite.project.context
    projectContext.driver = driver
```

**Get / Acessing the driver object else where:**

```
    def projectContext = context.testCase.testSuite.project.context
    def driver = projectContext.driver
    //then  use driver object below.
```

Comment: Thank you @Rao, I was playing around with the `context` variable over the weekend but i made it SO much more complicated  than adding two lines of code in each script :) simplicity is usually the answer - once again thanks for an awesome answer!